# SharePoint 2013 PowerShell List all Groups with Full Control

Tags: powershell

We have a huge SharePoint environment and not every Owner's group or admin group have full control on their site. I am looking to see if someone already made a script to show which group in the farm in all site have full control to their site for example

siteurl, groupname

thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here below is the PowerShell script to get all SharePoint user groups which has **Full Control** permission in sites for all web applications from server.

```
Add-PSSnapin "Microsoft.SharePoint.PowerShell"
$permissionName = "Full Control";
Write-Host "Name of groups which has" $permissionName " permission in sites from all web applications:"
$webApps = Get-SPWebApplication
foreach ($webApp in $webApps)
{
    Write-Host -ForegroundColor Gray "Web application: "$webApp.Name
    $sites = get-spsite $webApp.Url
    foreach ($site in $sites)
    {
        write-host -foregroundcolor green "Site Collection: "$site.RootWeb.Title
        foreach ($web in $site.AllWebs) 
        {
             write-host -foregroundcolor green "Web: "$web.Title
             foreach($roleAssignment in $web.RoleAssignments)
             {
                foreach($roleDefinition in $roleAssignment.RoleDefinitionBindings)
                {
                    if($roleDefinition.Name.ToString() -eq $permissionName)
                    {
                    write-host -foregroundcolor Cyan "Group Name: "$roleAssignment.Member.Name
                    break;
                    }
                }
            }
            $web.Dispose()
        }
        $site.Dispose()      
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks this pointed me in the right direction. I added an export-csv to it and all set. cheers